# Lim trace of inverse positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, trace, positive-definite

We have a symmetric positive definite matrix $A \in \Bbb R^{m \times m}$. How to calculate the following?

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \mbox{tr} \big( (\underbrace{A\cdot A\cdots A}_n)^{-1} - (\underbrace{A\cdot A\cdots A}_n + \underbrace{A\cdot A\cdots A}_{2n})^{-1} \big)$$

The main issue for me is how to transform the right-hand part of the expression containing inverse of the sum of matrices. The rest is more or less clear.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4625564/edit) the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've edited the question and pointed at the main issue that's puzzling me

Comment: @Family1 Do you have a reason to believe that this limit generally exists? This would be part of the "context" that the first comment was requesting.

Comment: @Family1 also, note that the expression can be more succinctly written as
$$
\operatorname{tr}[A^{-n} - (A^n + A^{2n})^{-1}]
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann, thanks for this succint form of the expression. I considered this before, however I don't see how this could help. I'm stuck with this inverse sum of the matrices.

As for existence of the limit, I'm not sure that the limit exists, however I hope so.

Comment: @Family1 Where did you encounter this expression in the first place?

Comment: @Family1 That is, *why* are you interested in this limit?

Answer (score 0):

Note that as $A$ is symmetric positive definite we can use the spectral theorem to write
$$
A = \sum_i \lambda_i P_i
$$
where $\lambda_i > 0$ are the eigenvalues (up to multiplicity) and $\{P_i\}_i$ form a set of orthogonal projectors onto the corresponding eigenspaces. Note that $\mathrm{Tr}[P_i] = d_i$ where $d_i$ is the dimension of the eigenspace.

From this form you can see that for example
$$
A^{k} = \sum_i \lambda_i^k P_i\,
$$
for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. And furthermore
$$
(A^n + A^{2n})^{-1} = \sum_i \frac{1}{\lambda_i^n + \lambda_i^{2n}} P_i
$$
Putting everything together we arrive at
$$
\mathrm{Tr}[A^{-n} - (A^n + A^{2n})^{-1}] = \sum_i d_i \left(\frac{1}{\lambda_i^n} - \frac{1}{\lambda_i^n + \lambda_i^{2n}}\right) = \sum_i d_i \frac{\lambda_i^{2n}}{\lambda_i^{2n} + \lambda_i^{3n}}
$$

Looking at each term in the sum individually they split into two cases. If $\lambda_i > 1$ then the term tends to $0$ otherwise if $0 < \lambda_i \leq 1$ then the term tends to $d_i$. Overall we find that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathrm{Tr}[A^{-n} - (A^n + A^{2n})^{-1}] = \sum_{i : \lambda_i \leq 1} d_i
$$
i.e., the total dimension of the eigenspaces corresponding to eigenvalues of $A$ that are no larger than $1$.